#  How to load current buffer into Python interpreter in Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs

I'm trying to use emacs to edit and run python programs (emacs23 and python 2.6 on Ubuntu 10.10).

- I read a file into Emacs (`C-x -C-f`)
- I start the interperter (Menu Python - Start interpreter, I haven't found the keyboard shortcut for this yet)
- Emacs split the frame in two windows
- I place the cursor in the python file (`C-x o`)

Now I want to run the Python code in the upper window in the Python interpreter in the lower window. Other places have suggested:

- `C-c C-c`, but that does nothing
- `C-c !`, but emacs says that that command is undefined

I have installed ropemacs (`sudo apt-get install python-ropemacs`) but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to hit "C-c C-z" (switch to interpreter) to see the results of and buffers or regions you evaluated.